# Installing a Subset of MiKTeX Packages to use RStudio knitr PDF Compiler

Tags: packages, miktex, knitr, rstudio

I would like to compile an R Markdown document using the knitr package in Rstudio on a Windows 7 OS using MiKTeX. RStudio recommends the complete installation of MiKTeX, this encompasses over [3,167 packages](http://www.miktex.org/pkg/az) as of today. Installing all of the packages is not an option that will work for me. I would like to find a subset of packages which will support the use of [knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) in RStudio for the compilation of PDFs. All documents will be in English and won't include mathematical notation. They will feature figures created using the ggplot2 package.

Comment: No idea about `knitr` or `R` myself but for general latex you can download a basic miktex installation and install packages on the fly - this can be quite slow first time you try compiling (if loading a lot of packages) but possibly that can be used as a sort-of auto detect for which packages are needed with `knitr`.

Comment: The LaTeX packages that must be installed depend of the LaTeX code generated by the markdown and the LaTeX code generated by the R chunks. May be none beside the basic MikTeX installation, may be two or three dozens of extra packages *only for that document*. If all these  packages must be downloaded and installed when you push the compile button, effectively it could be quite slow, and it can fail too.  At the end of day, a complete installation is faster and safer, at the cost of install of about 4 Gb, a ridiculous amount for today 0.25-3 Tb hard disks.

Answer (score 1):

The basic MikTeX installation works fine, you don't need to install the whole lot. When you run knitr for the first time, RStudio will download and install a handful of additional packages it needs. After that you only have to add more packages if your documents contain special features.